# Can I use MVC validation attributes within a custom model binder?

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-2, modelbinders

I have lots of MVC validation attributes on my model. Everything works great when the defaultModelBinder binds my model on submit. But, I need to create a custom modelbinder. I'd like to continue using my validation attributes. Can I? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is possible or not, but one thing I can say is that if it is possible then the extension points for default model binder don't make it very discoverable.  I spent several hours one day trying to get this to work to no avail.

In lieu of getting this to work, you can use the Controller's TryValidateModel() methods.